# Getting a better understanding of callback functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I understand passing in a function to another function as a callback and having it execute, but I'm not understanding the best implementation to do that. I'm looking for a very basic example, like this:

```
var myCallBackExample = {
    myFirstFunction : function( param1, param2, callback ) {
        // Do something with param1 and param2.
        if ( arguments.length == 3 ) {
            // Execute callback function.
            // What is the "best" way to do this?
        }
    },
    mySecondFunction : function() {
        myFirstFunction( false, true, function() {
            // When this anonymous function is called, execute it.
        });
    }
};
```

In myFirstFunction, if I do return new callback(), then it works and executes the anonymous function, but that doesn't seem like the correct approach to me.

Comment: Correct in what sense?  Typically callbacks are used for event handlers--most notably Ajax calls, which are asynchronous--basically things where you don't know when (or if) a resposne will come.

Comment: by the way arguments are array like  but not array , so you can't do argument.length but you can convert it into an array using slice method...

Comment: @paul, although you are right that `arguments` is not an array, you can still reference its length as `arguments.length` -- give it a try.  This property refers to the number of arguments actually passed in, and not necessarily the number of parameters in the function signature.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can just say

```
callback();
```

Alternately you can use the `call` method if you want to adjust the value of `this` within the callback.

```
callback.call( newValueForThis);
```

Inside the function `this` would be whatever `newValueForThis` is.

Answer (score 91):

You should check if the callback exists, and is an executable function:

```
if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
    // execute the callback, passing parameters as necessary
    callback();
}
```

A lot of libraries (jQuery, dojo, etc.) use a similar pattern for their asynchronous functions, as well as node.js for all async functions (nodejs usually passes `error` and `data` to the callback). Looking into their source code would help!

Comment: Why do you cast `callback` to string and then check its type? Will this enhance performance? This is like checking the type, checking if the converted boolean returns true and then checking its type again and testing it against the string... Could you explain why?

Comment: I am curious why you need the first assertion for callback... is it to check null or undefined?  Wouldn't `typeof(callback)` achieve that for you?  `typeof(null) === "Object"`, `typeof("undefined") === "undefined"`

Comment: Short-circuit AND. If the callback doesn't exist, don't bother computing its type. Though, you're right. It isn't needed with the typeof(), but I'll do a jsperf and see if the short-circuit is worth it.

Comment: @headacheCoder - `callback` is not being cast to a string, its type is being checked to see if it is a function, before it is called. The code presumably accepts `callback` as an argument, and is uncertain that the argument is of a callable type — or perhaps the arguments are of various types in an attempt to provide a form of polymorphism where code might react differently to different `typeof` arguments.

Answer (score 34):

There are 3 main possibilities to execute a function:

```
var callback = function(x, y) {
    // "this" may be different depending how you call the function
    alert(this);
};
```

1. callback(argument_1, argument_2);
2. callback.call(some_object, argument_1, argument_2);
3. callback.apply(some_object, [argument_1, argument_2]);

The method you choose depends whether:

1. You have the arguments stored in an Array or as distinct variables.
2. You want to call that function in the context of some object. In this case, using the "this" keyword in that callback would reference the object passed as argument in call() or apply(). If you don't want to pass the object context, use null or undefined. In the latter case the global object would be used for "this".

Docs for [Function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), 
[Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply)

Answer (score 6):

Callbacks are about signals and "new" is about creating object instances.

In this case it would be even more appropriate to execute just "callback();" than "return new callback()" because you aren't doing anything with a return value anyway.

*(And the arguments.length==3 test is really clunky, fwiw, better to check that callback param exists and is a function.)*

Answer (score 6):

the proper implementation would be:

```
if( callback ) callback();
```

this makes the callback parameter optional..

Comment: What if the callback argument is not a function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
    callback();
}
```

The below example is little more comprehensive:

```js
function mySandwich(param1, param2, callback) {
  alert('Started eating my sandwich.\n\nIt has: ' + param1 + ', ' + param2);
  var sandwich = {
      toppings: [param1, param2]
    },
    madeCorrectly = (typeof(param1) === "string" && typeof(param2) === "string") ? true : false;
  if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
    callback.apply(sandwich, [madeCorrectly]);
  }
}

mySandwich('ham', 'cheese', function(correct) {
  if (correct) {
    alert("Finished eating my " + this.toppings[0] + " and " + this.toppings[1] + " sandwich.");
  } else {
    alert("Gross!  Why would I eat a " + this.toppings[0] + " and " + this.toppings[1] + " sandwich?");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkCallback(cb) {
  if (cb || cb != '') {
    if (typeof window[cb] === 'undefined') alert('Callback function not found.');
    else window[cb].call(this, Arg1, Arg2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic example that explains the `callback()` function in JavaScript:

```js
var x = 0;

function testCallBack(param1, param2, callback) {
  alert('param1= ' + param1 + ', param2= ' + param2 + ' X=' + x);
  if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
    x += 1;
    alert("Calla Back x= " + x);
    x += 1;
    callback();
  }
}

testCallBack('ham', 'cheese', function() {
  alert("Function X= " + x);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Berguiga/f37ut5e4/2/)