# how to make custom alert in jquery +jqueryUi?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am making a custom alert from this url .
http://coding.abel.nu/2012/01/jquery-ui-replacement-for-alert/
I am able to make simple alert .But I need to do some work on "ok" button , use callback function.I got the error "undefined not function" .here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uV2Nv/

```
 $.extend({
        confirm: function(message, title, okAction) {
            $("").dialog({
                // Remove the closing 'X' from the dialog
                open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }, 
                buttons: {
                    "Ok": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        okAction();
                    },
                    "Cancel": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function(event, ui) { $(this).remove(); },
                resizable: false,
                title: title,
                modal: true
            }).text(message);
        }
    });

    function okAction(){
     alert('--')   
    }
    $.alert("message", "title",okAction)
```

Comment: that error is coming from `$.alert("message", "title", okAction)` There is no such function `.alert()`

Comment: @Adjit link written that it call $.extend({ function

Comment: it sounds like you want to be calling `$.confirm("message", "title", okAction)`

Comment: Why don't use alert("Your alert"); ?

here some precisions [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616181/callback-function-meaning][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616181/callback-function-meaning

Comment: actually I am making custom alert.to remove tittle of alert "javascript"

Comment: @Adjit not working on my side ..can you check on your side

Comment: change `$.alert` to `$.confirm` and give the dialog a div to use (`$("<div></div>").dialog`)