# Could anyone explain how the below code block works?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback, arrow-functions

How passing cats to func returns a callback?

```
let animal = '';
const fetchAnimal = func => {
  func('cats');
};

fetchAnimal(name => {
  //logs cats to the console
  console.log(name);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [callback function meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616181/callback-function-meaning)

Comment: See the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/callback/info).

Comment: Could you please clarify what you don't understand about this code? And also what do you mean by "How passing cats to func returns a callback" - i.e. what you think returns callback exactly?

Comment: Even better -- just call it with `fetchAnimal(console.log)`

Comment: Thanks. I can understand the context now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here we are passing a function as parameter to `fetchAnimal` in the function call which is mapped to `func` variable. so when you call `func('cats')` it's eventually calling the function you passed during the function call with `cats` as parameter which maps to variable `name`.

```js
const fetchAnimal = func => {
  func('cats');
};

fetchAnimal(name => {
  console.log(name);
});
```