# How to pass a callback as a parameter into another function

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, call

I'm new to ajax and callback functions, please forgive me if i get the concepts all wrong.

**Problem:** Could i send a ***callbackfunction*** as a parameter to another function that will execute the callback?

```
function firstFunction(){
    //some code

    //a callback function is written for $.post() to execute
    secondFunction("var1","var2",callbackfunction);
}

function secondFunction(var1, var2, callbackfunction) {
    params={}
    if (event != null) params = event + '&' + $(form).serialize();

    // $.post() will execute the callback function
    $.post(form.action,params, callbackfunction);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a better understanding of callback functions in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript)

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Yup. Function references are just like any other object reference, you can pass them around to your heart's content.

Here's a more concrete example:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log("Hello from foo!");
}

function caller(f) {
    // Call the given function
    f();
}

function indirectCaller(f) {
    // Call `caller`, who will in turn call `f`
    caller(f);
}

// Do it
indirectCaller(foo); // logs "Hello from foo!"
```

You can also pass in arguments for `foo`:

```js
function foo(a, b) {
    console.log(a + " + " + b + " = " + (a + b));
}

function caller(f, v1, v2) {
    // Call the given function
    f(v1, v2);
}

function indirectCaller(f, v1, v2) {
    // Call `caller`, who will in turn call `f`
    caller(f, v1, v2);
}

// Do it
indirectCaller(foo, 1, 2); // logs "1 + 2 = 3"
```

Answer (score 13):

Also, could be simple as:

```
if( typeof foo == "function" )
    foo();
```

Answer (score 11):

If you google for `javascript callback function example` you will get [Getting a better understanding of callback functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript)

This is how to do a callback function:

```
function f() {
    alert('f was called!');
}

function callFunction(func) {
    func();
}

callFunction(f);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course, function are objects and can be passed,  but of course you must declare it:

```
function firstFunction(){
    //some code
    var callbackfunction = function(data){
       //do something with the data returned from the ajax request
     }
    //a callback function is written for $.post() to execute
    secondFunction("var1","var2",callbackfunction);
}
```

an interesting thing is that your callback function has also access to every variable you might have declared inside firstFunction() (variables in javascript have local scope).

Answer (score 0):

Example for `CoffeeScript`:

```
test = (str, callback) ->
  data = "Input values"
  $.ajax
    type: "post"
    url: "http://www.mydomain.com/ajaxscript"
    data: data
    success: callback

test (data, textStatus, xhr) ->
  alert data + "\t" + textStatus
```

Comment: what does `->` mean in javascript ?@nothing-special-here

Comment: `->` is just a normal function.

`var test = function(str, callback) { ajax call }`

Comment: @shenkwen A thin arrow -> is CoffeeScript syntax, not JavaScript, and simply means a normal JavaScript function when compiled into JavaScript. JavaScript has a similar arrow function https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_arrow_function.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript CallBak like this:

```
var a;

function function1(callback) {
 console.log("First comeplete");
 a = "Some value";
 callback();
}
function function2(){
 console.log("Second comeplete:", a);
}


function1(function2);
```

Or Java Script Promise:

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
  // do function1 job
  let a = "Your assign value"
  resolve(a);
});

promise.then(             

function(a) {
 // do function2 job with function1 return value;
 console.log("Second comeplete:", a);
},
function(error) { 
 console.log("Error found");
});
```