# relationship between callbacks in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback

This question arises from a homework question in the 10gen MongoDB class which uses Node.js, however, I'm not asking you to solve the homework (which is about Mongo) rather to explain relationship between two functions. In a session.js file, the method `addUser` is called on a `users` data object module like this

```
      users.addUser(username, password, email, function(err, user) {
                "use strict";

                if (err) {
                    // this was a duplicate
                    if (err.code == '11000') {
                        errors['username_error'] = "Username already in use. Please choose another";
                        return res.render("signup", errors);
                    }
                    // this was a different error
                    else {
                        return next(err);
                    }
                }

                sessions.startSession(user['_id'], function(err, session_id) {
                    "use strict";

                    if (err) return next(err);

                    res.cookie('session', session_id);
                    return res.redirect('/welcome');
                });
            });
```

In the users data object module, there's a function `this.addUser` like this

```
 this.addUser = function(username, password, email, callback) {
        "use strict";

        // Generate password hash
        var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
        var password_hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

        // Create user document
        var user = {'_id': username, 'password': password_hash};

        // Add email if set
        if (email != "") {
            user['email'] = email;
        }

        //node convention first arg to call back error, 2nd the actual data we're returning, callbackwith value if added user
        // look in session.js file that uses the UsersDAO to get a sense of how this is being used and
        // what type of callback is passed in.Task is to fill in code to add a user when one tries to signup

        // TODO: hw2.3

        callback(Error("addUser Not Yet Implemented!"), null);

    }
```

We're supposed to implement the callback that enables the addition of the User into the mongo database. I'm not asking you to tell me that. Rather, the fourth argument to the users.addUser function is a callback function `function(err, user) { }`. Also, the `this.addUser` function has `callback` as the fourth  parameter, so the callback function from `users.addUser` runs inside `this.addUser?`  Can you help clarify the relationship between these two? I know that a callback runs when a function has finished but I don't know why it's being passed into `this.addUser`

Comment: it's being passed into this.addUser to that you can handle the success or error anyway you want.

Comment: You're not actually implementing the callback. The callback has been given. It's in the session.js snippet `function(err, user){..}`. You have to write the part the puts the user into the DB and returns any error. The last line of addUser says, given `callback`, execute it. Well how do we know what the callback signature looks like? By looking at what we're expecting from session.js. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`so the callback function from users.addUser runs inside this.addUser?`

That's exactly what is happening. As you probably already know, Javascript treats functions as [first-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). This means you can pass them around and return them just like other types. Functions are special because they have two additional fields in their prototype: the context in which they run and the function's code.

In your case, here is how this works:
1 - On the line `users.addUser(username, password, email, function(err, user) {...}`, you are calling `this.addUser` with the fourth parameter being **an anonymous function**. 
2- `this.addUser` assigns a variable name to this anonymous function, calling it **callback**.
3- In the case of an error, callback is executed (since it is a function) with an error object `Error("addUser Not Yet Implemented!")` and `null` as parameters. These stand for `err` and `user` as declared in your first line.

---

An example that you are probably familiar with is that of `setTimeout`. [This function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) is defined as:
`var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);`. The method `setTimeout` does not really care what `func` is, as long it can execute it. Assume the following code, for example:

```
var delay = 30 * 1000;
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "This text will change in "+delay/1000+" sec";
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "told ya!";
}, delay);
```

Here, again, we are passing a callback, that will be executed in the future. One cool thing is that this callback has access to the scope of `setTimeout`, which means it can use the variables defined in that scope. In the case of `setTimeout`, this isn't really useful, but, in your `this.addUser`, you have access to the error object that originated from the creation operation.

For more details on how callbacks work, check out these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466031/how-to-pass-callback-as-a-parameter-into-another-function).

Comment: i am getting this error, any idea on this  Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback