# cursor.toArray(callback) does not return an array of documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to return an array that contains documents of the decks collection.
I can get the cursor to point to those documents and then I use the toArray() function to turn them into an array.

The problem is that I cannot return the converted array... please take a look at my code.

```
exports.find_by_category = function (category_id){
    var results = []; //Array where all my results will be
    console.log('Retrieving decks of category: ' + category_id);
    mongo.database.collection('decks', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({'category_id': category_id}).toArray(function(err,items){
            results = items; //Items is an array of the documents
        });
    }); 
    return results; //The problems is here, results seems to be empty...
};
```

I honestly dont know what is going on since `results` is in the outer-scope. What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve returning `results` as an array of the found documents.

Comment: What's going on is that the call to `.collection()` is **asynchronous**. The results are not available immediately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @Pointy pointed out, the line `return results` is executed synchronously, way before the call to `collection.find` has returned any results.

The way to solve this is to provide a callback to the function, like so:

```
exports.find_by_category = function (category_id, callback){ //Notice second param here  
    mongo.database.collection('decks', function(err, collection) {
       collection.find({'category_id': category_id}).toArray(function(err,items){
           if(err) callback(err);
           else callback(null, items);
        });
    }); 
};
```

For a better understanding of how callbacks work, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466031/how-to-pass-callback-as-a-parameter-into-another-function?lq=1). And yes, async programming is hard at first, and does require some getting used to.