# Run anonymous function inside another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

My code:

```
function myFunc(callback) { /*do stuff*/
    $('div').one('mouseover', function () {
        alert('mouseover');
        callback;
    });
}
$("div").click(function () {
    alert('clicked');
    myFunc(function () {
        alert('Callback');
    });
});
```

However, `callback` does not execute, nor is there an error in the console. How can I make this work?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z66u/

Comment: `callback();`. If you don't call the function, it's not executed. Function basics: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8Z66u/1/ - use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging

Comment: @ArunPJohny I generally do, but this is a short piece of code.

Comment: and [How to pass callback as a parameter into another function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6466031/218196)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are forgetting to invoke with `()`

```
function myFunc(callback) { /*do stuff*/
    $('div').one('mouseover', function () {
        alert('mouseover');
        callback(); // invoke
    });
}
```

Without `()`, you've just got a reference to the *function* `callback` but doing no action with it, so the line basically does nothing.

Comment: I think you mean `.on('mouseover'` instead of `.one('mouseover'`.

Comment: @Anonymous I only want it to execute once.

Comment: @Anonymous http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: My mistake.  Sorry for the confusion.