# Calling custom functions on click (javascript / jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am a beginner and having a problem with calling functions that I create on JavaScript or jQuery.

if i use this, it works:

```
$("#objectId").click(function(){
    alert("Clicked on objectId")
}
```

however if I pre-define a function and call it onclick it doesn't work

```
function alertOnClick(objectToClick) {
    alert("Clicked on " + objectToClick)
}
$("#objectId").click(alertOnClick("objectId"))
```

in this case, it gives the alert when the page is loaded and it does not alert on click.

What am I doing wrong syntax-wise and why?

Thank you very much

Comment: It should be either `$("#objectId").click(function() { alertOnClick("objectId") })` or `$("#objectId").click(alertOnClick)` and `alert("Clicked on " + this.id)` within the function.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling the function `alertOnClick` instead of passing it as reference

You should be doing something like this:

`$("#objectId").click(alertOnClick)`

```
function alertOnClick(ev) {
    alert("Clicked on " + ev.target.id);
}
```

When you do `$("#objectId").click(alertOnClick("objectId"))` you are calling the `alertOnClick` method with `objectId` as parameter before the click event happens. What you should do is pass the reference of the method so it is called when the `click` event happens.

Comment: thank you. do you have a blog post link or a recommended resource that I can read to further grasp the differences between reference to a method and calling a function and which should be used on a click event? I now know what to do, but just as a memorization rather than learning/understanding it

Comment: @textmachina Sure, stackoverflow has many questions/answers related to the subject. You can check this one for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466031/how-to-pass-a-callback-as-a-parameter-into-another-function or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to return a function from `alertOnClick` as shown:

```
function alertOnClick(objectToClick) {
  return function() {
    alert("Clicked on " + objectToClick)
  }
}
```

Which will allow you to do the following:

```
$("#objectId").click(alertOnClick("objectId"))
```

Here's a working code sample to see it in action:

```js
function alertOnClick(objectToClick) {
  return function() {
    alert("Clicked on " + objectToClick)
  }
}

$("#objectId").click(alertOnClick("objectId"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="objectId">Object Id</button>
```

Comment: isn't `function() {...}` used to define a one-use function on the spot? this way you define a function that returns a function? why can't I use the function in the first place? thank you

Comment: Hi @textmachina, yes - function() {..} is used to define a function on the stop. In javascript however, it is also valid to have a function (ie the outer) that returns a new function (ie the inner) as shown in my answer. In the case of my answer, when setting up `$("#objectId").click(alertOnClick("objectId"))` the outer function is getting called immedialty with argument 'objectId'. Calling `alertOnClick('objectId')` results in a new function being returned to the `click` handler - the neat thing about this is that the returned function is parameterised by the outer function. Hope this helps!