# How to apply a callback function in framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery-callback, html-framework-7

i am trying to get the GPS location of a user for all my services i have created a separated file let Say `Factory.js`

This is the code in my factory file:

```
var get_my_location=function(){

        var onSuccess = function(position) {
        if(typeof position ==='object'){

            return position
        }
        else{
            return 500;
}
    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
       return {"err":error}
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
```

i want to call and get the position in response when any other function calls this `get_my_location();`

When i am trying like:

```
var resp=get_my_location();
console.log(resp) //outpur 'undefined'
```

obviously it should give undefined,how can i apply a callback so that i may get the position in resp as a returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you can pass callback. Below is a link where you can get more information.

[Getting a better understanding of callback functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript)

```
function vinoth() {
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = "Kalam";
    return obj;
}

function callFunction(func) {
    var newValue = func();
    console.log(newValue);
}

callFunction(vinoth);
```

Comment: how if my function vinoth is returning some object and i wan to print it as a return value of callFunction ?