# Handling event method with parameter without inserting parameter

Tags: reactjs

I attached a picture describing my question. I cannot understand what is a mechanism of sending this parameter. How is it possible, that React knows what value to send when we dont insert any parameter into calling function?

I really beg explanation, i am desperate from it. I need to understand that mechanism in order to do other things.

Here is a photo describing my problem:

[image]

Here is the WHOLE code (you can smoothly start it):

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyCheckbox from "./MyCheckbox";

const items = ["One", "Two", "Three"];

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
  };

  toggleCheckbox = label => {
    if (this.selectedCheckboxes.has(label)) {
      this.selectedCheckboxes.delete(label);
    } else {
      this.selectedCheckboxes.add(label);
    }

    for (const checkbox of this.selectedCheckboxes) {
      console.log(checkbox, "is selected.");
    }
  };

  createCheckbox = label => (
    <MyCheckbox
      label={label}
      handleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckbox}
      key={label}
    />
  );

  createCheckboxes = () => items.map(this.createCheckbox);

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-12">{this.createCheckboxes()}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

MyCheckbox.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class MyCheckbox extends Component {
  state = {
    isChecked: false
  };

  toggleCheckboxChange = () => {
    const { handleCheckboxChange, label } = this.props;

    this.setState(({ isChecked }) => ({
      isChecked: !isChecked
    }));

    handleCheckboxChange(label);
  };

  render() {
    const { label } = this.props;
    const { isChecked } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={label}
            checked={isChecked}
            onChange={this.toggleCheckboxChange}
          />

          {label}
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyCheckbox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible, that React knows what value to send when we dont insert any parameter into calling function?

It doesn't.

`Array.prototype.map` iterates over the array and calls the callback for each element, passing that element to the callback.

Here is a simpler example:

```js
console.log(
  [1,2,3].map(x => x + 1)
)
```

You can think `Array.prototype.map` to be implemented approximately like this:

```js
function map(callback) {
  // `this` is the array
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result.push(callback(this[i]));
    //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(map.call([1,2,3], x => x + 1));
```

---

`this.toggleChechkbox` on the other hand gets the label as argument because `MyCheckbox` explicitly passes it in

```
const { handleCheckboxChange, label } = this.props;
// ...
handleCheckboxChange(label);
```

---

So, as you hopefully see, there is no magic going on. `Array.prototype.map` is implemented in such a way that each element is passed to the callback.

And you created `MyCheckbox` so that it passes `label` to the handler.

React is not involved here at all.

**Related:**

- [Create a custom callback in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2190850/218196)
- [Getting a better understanding of callback functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483073/getting-a-better-understanding-of-callback-functions-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi, thanks, i understand the orange arrow explanation, but i still dont understand the red arrow on the picture. How come that label appears there, i dont realize that some callback would return label value. Where program sends that label value?

Comment: The orange one is the simpler one. *You* are calling `toggleCheckbox` here: `handleCheckboxChange(label);` Where does `handleCheckboxChange` and `label` come from? You're passing it as props to `MyCheckbox` here: `<MyCheckbox label={label} handleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckbox} key={label} />`. There isn't anything more to that...